# Save a dataframe name and then reference that object in subsequent code

Tags: r, dataframe, reference

Would like to reference a dataframe name stored in an object, such as:

```
dfName <- 'mydf1'
dfName <- data.frame(c(x = 5)) #want dfName to resolve to 'mydf1', not create a dataframe named 'dfName'
mydf1
```

Instead, I get: Error: object 'mydf1' not found

CORRECTED SCENARIO:

```
olddf <- data.frame(c(y = 8)) 
mydf1 <- data.frame(c(x = 5))
assign('dfName', mydf1)
dfName <- olddf #why isnt this the same as doing "mydf1 <- olddf"?
```

I don't want to reference an actual dataframe named "`dfName`", rather "`mydf1`".

UPDATE
I have found a clunky workaround for what I wanted to do. The code is:

```
olddf <- data.frame(x = 8)
olddfName <- 'olddf'
newdfName <- 'mydf1'
statement <- paste(newdfName, "<-", olddfName, sep = " ")
writeLines(statement, "mycode.R")
source("mycode.R")
```

Anyone have a more elegant way, especially without resorting to a write/source?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to store multiple `data.frame`s in a loop or similar. In that case it is much more efficient and better to store them in a named `list`. However, you can achieve your goal with `assign`

```
assign('mydf1', data.frame(x = 5))
mydf1
  x
1 5
```

Comment: Added some code above to further show what I'm trying to do. Is it possible there is  some restriction in R that names on the left side of ```<-``` cannot be a reference?

Comment: I am not getting the same error as you are getting, are you looking for having a pointer from `mydf1` through `dfName`? Eg. If `mydf1` changed you want that to happen in `dfName` as well.

Comment: Sorry...must have been some leftover objects in memory. Corrected the scenario...any thoughts?

Comment: Aha, yes. In R there's nothing such as "Assign by reference". Basically this means that whenever you change something, overwrite something or similar, a copy of the object you change, overwrite, etc is assigned to the variable. Therefore `x <- 3; z <- x; z <- 2; x` will return 3, as `z` doesn't *reference* x. It is a copy of x. There are some details I'm leaving out here with lazy loading, but in practice this is how you'll observe evaluation.

Comment: Oliver...nice reply! I did just think of a way (but clunky) to do what I think I want to do. See my update above.